# Add a if statement condition to a Linq statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am wanting a nice clean approach to adding in a conditional to an existing linq statement .   I have a NEW variable `personContactRoleId` which will be zero or not zero.

```
context.PersonContactRoles
          .Where(pcr => pcr.PersonId == personId);                        
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(pcr =>
          {
              // a lot of code
          }
```

**I was able to solve it with the iqueryable deferment of execution using an if statement, but it seems rather ugly and possibly less performant?  Anything better to use?**

```
var query = context.PersonContactRoles
          .Where(pcr => pcr.PersonId == personId);                        

if(personContactRoleId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.PersonContactRoleId == personContactRoleId);
}

var results = query.ToList();
results.ForEach(pcr =>
{
    // a lot of code
}
```

**Again, this works, but looking for a cleaner way of doing this**

Comment: The `if` statement there in your 2nd code sample doesn't make things slower. How could it...

Comment: @elgonzo I'd wager that many people are not properly aware of the lazy loading involved with LINQ and believe that the first `query` is processed, then the `if` statement is processed and if it falls into it then the `query` is modified. It's an obvious thing if you're familiar with how it all works, but if you're not then you're likely to think that it follows that pattern I just described thus making you think it's slow and is actually enumerating the query twice, not once. Just my guess.

Comment: @gilliduck, my comment was directed at the OP, obviously. Chad himself is already aware of the deferred execution nature of Linq queryables (excluding queries producing a singleton value). Note the text written in bold there in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have is fine, but if you want to put it all into one query without an `if`, you can add an additional `Where` condition that returns records where either `personContactRoleId == 0` or `prc.PersonContactRoleId == personContactRoleId` is true:

```
context.PersonContactRoles
    .Where(pcr =>
        pcr.PersonId == personId &&
        (personContactRoleId == 0 || pcr.PersonContactRoleId == personContactRoleId))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(pcr =>
    {
        // a lot of code
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This works without a need for an if block that checks that personContactRoleId is not 0

```
var query = context.PersonContactRoles
              .Where(pcr => pcr.PersonId == personId).Where(b => {
    return b.PersonContactRoleId == personContactRoleId && personContactRoleId != 0

    }).ToList().ForEach(pcr =>
    {
        // a lot of code
    }
```

Comment: This is different from the original code, however, where they want to add all records when `personContactRoleId == 0`, and only filter them if `personContactRoleId != 0`...